# cronjobs: Run every day "except" when weekly/monthly/yearly is running

Tags: bash, math, cron, debian-buster

I currently have this to always run 6 o'clock. Once.

```
0 6 * * 1-6 server.sh backup  daily  # Run Monday-Saturday
0 6 * * 0 server.sh backup weekly    # Run every Sunday
```

And they will sometimes collide with because of how time works:

```
0 6 1 2-12 * server.sh backup  monthly # Run 1st day of month (feb-dec)
0 6 1 1 *  server.sh backup   yearly # Run 1st of January
```

I've previously shifted time for weekly/monthly/yearly so that they never run at the same time.
I'd hope there is an easy way with cronjob to run at 6 every day and sort out daily/weekly/monthly/yearly

Year should take presence over Month, Week and Day, Month over week and day.

Comment: Are they running different commands? Because the way you show it, it's always the same command and there's no point in doing anything other than `0 6 * * * server.sh backup`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Omitted that last minute. There is a sub command for naming the output depending on the interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the daily and weekly jobs, you can check if the day of the month is `1` and only run if it isn't:

```
0 6 * * 1-6 [ "$(date '+%%-d')" -ne 1 ] && server.sh backup daily   # Run Monday-Saturday
0 6 * * 0   [ "$(date '+%%-d')" -ne 1 ] && server.sh backup weekly  # Run every Sunday
```

The formatting directive `+%%-d` is "day of month, without zero padding".

The `%%` has to be doubled up, or cron interprets it as a newline character.

Some versions of `date` don't support the `-` to remove the zero padding and it isn't really required here because `[ 01 -eq 1 ]` is true (but `[ 01 = 1 ]` isn't!), but it's cleaner.

Comment: This looks promising! I'll try this. I'm going to mark it as a solution for now!

Comment: My version of date is 8.30 (from GNU coreutils)